# Isn't the size of Delphi TFileStream WriteBuffer Int64? I'm only able to write small amounts at a time

Tags: delphi, tfilestream

I'm trying to write larger chunks to increase the speed of the file save. I have about 9 of these loops to convert but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

```
fs := TFileStream.Create(Myfile, fmCreate);
```

This code works:

```
for RecordGroup := 0 to TotalGroups - 1 do
begin
  for RecordNumber := 0 to Length(MyArray[RecordGroup]) - 1 do
  begin
    fs.WriteBuffer(MyArray[RecordGroup,RecordNumber],SizeOf(MyRecord));
  end;
end;
```

When I remove the innerloop to write bigger chunks, the code does not work:

```
for RecordGroup := 0 to TotalGroups - 1 do
begin
  fs.WriteBuffer(MyArray[RecordGroup],SizeOf(MyRecord) * Length(MyArray[RecordGroup]));
end;
```

I get the generic error 'Stream write error'

The value of `SizeOf(MyRecord) * Length(MyArray[RecordGroup])` is 180 * 152,004 = 27,360,720

Everything I've read basically says this is correct. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any ideas you may have.

Comment: actually it will let you only reach 2gb read my Q https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48039254

Comment: LU RD, I forgot to subtract 1. I edited to correct. Is that what you meant by conspicuous?

Comment: Yes, the code would not have worked properly without it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change writing code to  (note additional 0 in square brackets)

```
fs.WriteBuffer(MyArray[RecordGroup, 0],   SizeOf(MyRecord) * Length(MyArray[RecordGroup]));
```

Mistake was in wrong dynamic array usage. I assume that `MyArray` is two-dimensional array, so `MyArray[RecordGroup]` is 1D dynamic array - essentially pointer to data - but untyped var-parameter of `WriteBuffer` requires using of array data body.

---

Aside note - your for-loop counter goes from 0 to `TotalGroups`, so overall number of loops is `TotalGroups + 1`. Is it correct?

Comment: Thank you MBo! I was so focused on the Count parameter, it didn't occur to me that it might be the array. Also I did forget to subtract 1 from the loop. I edited to fix that.